# Handle change event not working for input types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react… my handle change event is not working while typing text into an `input`. How do I go about fixing that? I want to handle both `inputs` with the same handle change.

```
import React from 'react'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
class Settings extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            first_name:'',
            last_name:''
        }
    }
    handleChange(e){
        var first_name = e.target.first_name
        var last_name = e.target.last_name
        var state = this.state
        state[first_name] = e.target.value
        state[last_name] = e.target.value
        this.setState(state)
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              <TextField hint text="First Name" id="user_first_name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" value={this.state.first_name} />
              <TextField hint text="Last Name" id="user_last_name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" name="user[last_name]" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} size="30" type="text" value={this.state.last_name} />
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly not working?

Comment: while i am typing the text .... there is nothing showing in input boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on id you should update the state and not both on them together. Try the below method. Also change the ids

```js
import React from 'react'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
class Settings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
     this.state = {
      first_name:'',
      last_name:''
    }
  }
  handleChange(e){
     this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
            <TextField hint text="First Name" id="first_name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" value={this.state.first_name} />
            <TextField hint text="Last Name" id="last_name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" name="user[last_name]" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} size="30" type="text" value={this.state.last_name} />
      </div>
  )}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as you're using material-ui/TextField component updating state by target.id can't work, because TextField component doesn't pass your id to its input, so you can do it by adding second parameter to your handleChange function, like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
class Settings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
     this.state = {
      first_name:'',
      last_name:''
    }
  }
  handleChange(value, param){
     this.setState({[param]: value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
            <TextField hint text="First Name" id="first_name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.value, 'first_name')} name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" value={this.state.first_name} />
            <TextField hint text="Last Name" id="last_name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" name="user[last_name]" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.value, 'last_name')} size="30" type="text" value={this.state.last_name} />
      </div>
  )}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, issue is you are updating both the fields by the same value, write it like this:

```
handleChange(e){
    var obj = {}
    obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState(obj);
}
```

And assign the same name as the state variable names, like this:

```
<TextField ... name='first_name' value={this.state.first_name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
<TextField ... name='last_name' value={this.state.last_name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}   />
```

Use this:

```
class Settings extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
     this.state = {
      first_name:'',
      last_name:''
    }
  }

  handleChange(e){
    let obj = {};
    obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField hintText="First Name" id="first_name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} name="first_name" size="30" type="text" value={this.state.first_name} />
        <TextField hinText="Last Name" id="last_name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" name="last_name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} size="30" type="text" value={this.state.last_name} />
      </div>
  )}
}
```

Comment: @AshishChoudhary check the updated answer, use this it will work and update both the fields separately :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Settings extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  handleChange=(e)=>{
const {name,value}=e.target;
    this.setState({[name]=value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField hintText="First Name" floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" onChange={this.handleChange} name="first_name" size="30" type="text" />
        <TextField hinText="Last Name"floatingLabelFixed="editprofile" name="last_name" onChange={this.handleChange} size="30" type="text"/>
      </div>
  )}
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.